# How to insert characters before rectangular block selection in JOE Editor?

Tags: joe-editor

When you have made a rectangular block selection in Joe (using `^TX`, `^KB [move cursor] ^KK`), how can you use it to insert characters on multiple lines?

For instance, say we have this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Pellentesque pretium elementum eros,
ac dignissim purus volutpat et. Integer eleifend, odio.
```

And we want to change it to:

```
% Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
% adipiscing elit. Pellentesque pretium elementum eros,
% ac dignissim purus volutpat et. Integer eleifend, odio.
```

I want this specifically for LaTeX, but this situation of wanting to comment out a multi-line block appears in many other contexts.

I know this is possible by setting up a macro and repeating it across multiple lines, but it would be good to be able to make arbitrary multi-line insertions and deletions as needed.

Is this even possible in Joe? How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your block of text (cursor to 'L' in 'Lorem', ^KB, cursor to '.' in 'odio.', ^KK), then filter it (^K/) through, sed -e 's/^/% /' (or perl -lne 'print qq(% ),$_', or awk, or...).  Yes, it's possible. :-)